# PDF version 1.7 output using XeLaTex and texlive 2017

Tags: xetex, pdf, texlive-2017

I tried to use \pdfminorversion=7. This did not work, the error "!Undefined control sequence" popped up.
Just to see if it would work, I also entered \pdfminorversion=2, with the same effect.
Is there a possibility to create PDF version 1.7 with texlive 2017 using XeLaTeX?
Are there packages or something else needed in addition?
Due to a quite complex system that would not work otherwise, I have no possibility to update texlive or use something else instead of XeLaTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\special` to set the version:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0} %to uncompress and check
\special{pdf:minorversion 7} %set minorversion


\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly!